# Flatten a has_many association and get an attribute sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

I would like to understand the most efficient way to flatten some has_many associations, and subsequently get the sum of some attribute on the child associations. Suppose you have the following data structures:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address
    has_many :menu_items
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end

class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :restaurant
end
```

Say that MenuItem has the attribute "cost", and Address has the attribute "zip_code". What I would like to do is maybe find all restaurants in the zipcode '10101' and get the sum of their menu item's cost attributes. Say that I want to be able to show the average cost of restaurants' offerings in an area.

I think there are quite a few brute force-y ways to do this, but I know there should be something better. For example, in C#/LINQ if I had a similar set of data structures it would be easy to write:

```
var sum=restaurants.Where(r => r.zip_code==10101).SelectMany(r => r.MenuItems).Sum(mi => mi.Cost);
```

The best I have come up with, but that feels wrong to me, is:

```
def thing_I_dont_know_how_to_do
    find_zip=Address.where(:zip_code => zip_code)
    restaurants=Restaurant.joins(:address, :menu_items).merge(find_zip)
    restaurant_ids=restaurants.map(&:id)

    sum=MenuItems.sum(:cost, :conditions => {:restaurant_ids => venue_ids})
end
```

Can anyone help me improve upon this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single SQL request which selects all the menu items of restaurants in zip code 10101, and sums all their cost:

```
MenuItem.joins(restaurant: :address).where(addresses: { zip_code: '10101' }).sum('cost')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working, I get the following error. I'm investigating, but perhaps it's immediately clear to you:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "restaurant"
LINE 1: ..." ON "addresses"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id" WHERE "restaurant"."a...

Comment: @Kevek Could you post the entire SQL query generated (it should be printed in the logs). Also make sure in the where clause `restaurants` and `addresses` are plural (as the table name).

Comment: Here is what I'm getting, though once I corrected the pluralization of the "restaurants" in the where clause I get a different error.

The new error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column restaurants.addresses does not exist

The SQL:

: SELECT SUM("menu_items"."cost") AS sum_id FROM "menu_items" INNER JOIN "restaurants" ON "restaurants"."id" = "menu_items"."restaurant_id" INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id" WHERE "restaurants"."address" = '---
:zip_code: ''10101''
'

Comment: @Kevek maybe `restaurants` is not needed in the where clause. I've updated my answer.